# Getting NSTableView's selected string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My NSTableView lists some strings. I managed to fill the list with strings and react whenever the user selects a new option. However, I am having trouble getting the string that is being chosen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your strings are being held in an array (`dataSourceArray`) which you are using as the table's (`tableView`) data source:

```
NSString *selectedStringValue = [dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:[tableView selectedRow]];
```

If you are doing anything more complicated than that you will have to add more detail to your question, perhaps how you are deriving the values in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at the NSTableViewDelegate protocol. The table view notifies its delegate when the selection chages by calling `tableViewSelectionDidChange:`. You can implement that method, ask the table view which row(s) are selected and pull the relevant data from your datasource array.